# import org.apache.spark.SparkConf not working in Spark-shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am using spark 3.0.0-preview2. When I open Spark-shell, it opens perfectly but when I try to import org.apache.spark.SparkConf I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-16" java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\mail2\.scala_history (Access is denied)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(FileOutputStream.java:270)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:213)
    at scala.reflect.io.File.outputStream(File.scala:66)
    at scala.reflect.io.File.writer(File.scala:74)
    at scala.reflect.io.File.bufferedWriter(File.scala:81)
    at scala.reflect.io.File.bufferedWriter(File.scala:79)
    at scala.reflect.io.File.appendAll(File.scala:93)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.FileBackedHistory.append(FileBackedHistory.scala:75)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.FileBackedHistory.append$(FileBackedHistory.scala:74)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.JLineHistory$JLineFileHistory.append(JLineHistory.scala:57)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.FileBackedHistory.addLineToFile(FileBackedHistory.scala:64)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.FileBackedHistory.addLineToFile$(FileBackedHistory.scala:62)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.JLineHistory$JLineFileHistory.addLineToFile(JLineHistory.scala:57)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.JLineHistory$JLineFileHistory.add(JLineHistory.scala:63)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.finishBuffer(ConsoleReader.java:733)

    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.accept(ConsoleReader.java:2025)scala> import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2698)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2378)
    at jline.console.ConsoleReader.readLine(ConsoleReader.java:2366)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.InteractiveReader.readOneLine(JLineReader.scala:63)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.InteractiveReader.readLine(InteractiveReader.scala:45)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.InteractiveReader.readLine$(InteractiveReader.scala:42)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.jline.InteractiveReader.readLine(JLineReader.scala:31)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.SplashReader.readLine(InteractiveReader.scala:154)
    at scala.tools.nsc.interpreter.SplashLoop.run(InteractiveReader.scala:82)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

I have checked access to .scala_history and it is allowed for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

Run your spark-shell with Administrator privileges.